# Using loops and arrays to switch between players in a quiz game

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I'm in the process of writing a very simple quiz-style boardgame that moves players around the board based on if they answer the question correctly and what they roll on the dice. I'm attempting to create and pass an array mehtod that stores the scores of player 1 and player 2, but the array doesn't seem to actually keep track of the score. For example, a fragment of some of the code is as follows:

```
public static int[] scorearray 
{
   int scoreplayer1 = 0;
   int scoreplayer2 = 0;
   return new int[] = {scoreplayer1, scoreplayer2};
}

public static int questions(int diceroll, int[] score)
{
   String textinput = input("What's 9+10?");
   int ans = Integer.parseInt(textinput);
      if (ans == 19)
      {
         output("Fantastic answer, that's correct!");
         diceroll = dicethrow(diceroll); // rolls the dice
         output("Move forward " + diceroll + " squares. You are on square " + score[0]); 
         //I need the output above to print position 0 in the above array
         score[0] = score[0] + diceroll; //array stores the cumulative score
      }
      else
      {
         output("Sorry, the answer was 19. Next player's turn.")
         //This is where I need the loop to switch between players
      }
```

In addition, I need to come up with a way of switching between player 1 and 2 while also switching to the position 1 in the above array, that is, I need to add to player two's score instead of player one's. I've been combing through this code for ages now trying to figure out how to do this but I can only come up with the idea of using a for/while loop. Other than that I'm truly stumped.

Thanks.

EDIT: It appears that my array apparently still does not store the score when being used in the method `questions`.

Also I have now realised I can control whose turn it is by creating another method, for example `public static void activePlayer()` but I'm still not sure how to use a loop (or anything else for that matter) to switch between the two. Also my concern is where I use `score[0] = score[0] + diceroll;` in my `questions` method only keeps the score (or at least attempts to; see above problem) for player one. How would I switch it to keep score for `score[1]`? Please.

Comment: java is pass by value so when you update score inside of the questions method it isn't changing the score outside of that function

Comment: You haven't shared all of you code but likely you want to use a class instead of just static methods for this

Comment: @pwilmot I would love to share more, but I'm dealing with about 500 lines of really messy code so I tried to give the best parts I could. Also I've only been taught to use `public static xxx` in my methods, just using one class at the start of my code. I wouldn't know how to use a class to achieve what I need. Also how would I then go about getting the score to update outside of the questions?

Answer (score 0):

your options here seem to be either have your questions function output the score or change your score object to be a static object instead of a static function.

```
public static int[] scorearray = [0,0];
```

or

```
public static int[] questions(int diceroll, int[] score)
```

Comment: try making another static field which is activePlayer

Comment: How would I change between player 1 and 2 in that method? Also, in my `public static int questions(int diceroll, int[] score)` method I have used `score[0]++;` to keep track of the score. When it switches to player 2 I need it to do `score[1]++;` instead but how can I do this without writing the same method twice (it's about 200 lines of code :/)?

Comment: Admittedly I told you I understood what you had written and said that it worked. It appeared to me that it had until I put some code in to print out the score array and realised it was still printing out `0`. Could you please outline what you mean by your answer, it would help me out a huge deal! @pwilmot